# json file query error on pull of ratings from scores json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my pulling script for the json file...
I have no idea how to pull the scores section and have tried multiple ways...
This method works to pull the full score section - I am after the id and or even the rating section...

```
var link = jsonEscape((data["requests"][0]["response_body"]));
```

this method does not work...

```
var link = jsonEscape((data["requests"][0]["response_body"]["scores"][0]["id"]));
```

What am I doing wrong... 
find below my full code ....

```
<div id="link"></div>
<script>
var link_name = "./api/scores/list_all_scores.json"

$.getJSON(link_name,
function(data){

function jsonEscape(str)  {
    return str.replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/\r/g, "").replace(/\t/g, "");
}

var link = jsonEscape((data["requests"][0]["response_body"]));
document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = link;
});
</script>
```

This is my json file...

```
{
  "resource": "Scores",
  "http_method": "GET",
  "route": "/scores",
  "description": "List all scores",
  "explanation": null,
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "page",
      "description": "Fetch the nth page"
    },
    {
      "name": "per_page",
      "description": "Number of objects per page"
    },
    {
      "name": "offset",
      "description": "Pad a number of records"
    }
  ],
  "response_fields": [

  ],
  "requests": [
    {
      "request_method": "GET",
      "request_path": "/scores",
      "request_body": null,
      "request_headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Host": "example.org",
        "Cookie": ""
      },
      "request_query_parameters": {

      },
      "request_content_type": "application/json",
      "response_status": 200,
      "response_status_text": "OK",
      "response_body": "{\n  \"scores\": [\n    {\n      \"id\": 1,\n      \"value\": 3,\n      \"subject\": {\n        \"id\": 1,\n        \"fullname\": \"Elza Greenfelder\",\n        \"email\": \"greyson_lebsack@skiles.biz\",\n        \"address\": \"Teufenerstrasse\",\n        \"latitude\": null,\n        \"longitude\": null\n      },\n      \"topic\": {\n        \"id\": 1,\n        \"name\": \"Tag Case\"\n      },\n      \"ratings\": [\n        {\n          \"id\": 1,\n          \"value\": 1\n        },\n        {\n          \"id\": 2,\n          \"value\": 1\n        },\n        {\n          \"id\": 3,\n          \"value\": 2\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    {\n      \"id\": 2,\n      \"value\": 3,\n      \"subject\": {\n        \"id\": 8,\n        \"fullname\": \"Raven Witting\",\n        \"email\": \"jane_rempel@leffler.co.uk\",\n        \"address\": \"Durachweg\",\n        \"latitude\": null,\n        \"longitude\": null\n      },\n      \"topic\": {\n        \"id\": 5,\n        \"name\": \"Tag Filter\"\n      },\n      \"ratings\": [\n        {\n          \"id\": 4,\n          \"value\": 2\n        },\n        {\n          \"id\": 5,\n          \"value\": 1\n        },\n        {\n          \"id\": 6,\n          \"value\": 3\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    {\n      \"id\": 3,\n      \"value\": 2,\n      \"subject\": {\n        \"id\": 15,\n        \"fullname\": \"Cristopher Buckridge\",\n        \"email\": \"tamia_rippin@bailey.biz\",\n        \"address\": \"Teufenerstrasse\",\n        \"latitude\": null,\n        \"longitude\": null\n      },\n      \"topic\": {\n        \"id\": 9,\n        \"name\": \"Digital Viewer\"\n      },\n      \"ratings\": [\n        {\n          \"id\": 7,\n          \"value\": 1\n        },\n        {\n          \"id\": 8,\n          \"value\": 2\n        },\n        {\n          \"id\": 9,\n          \"value\": 3\n        }\n      ]\n    }\n  ]\n}",
      "response_headers": {
        "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Total": "3",
        "X-Total-Pages": "1",
        "X-Per-Page": "25",
        "X-Page": "1",
        "X-Next-Page": "",
        "X-Prev-Page": "",
        "X-Offset": "",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "ETag": "W/\"f1efdc568cbd238621cce62d52455417\"",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate",
        "X-Request-Id": "1dfccc08-e28e-4068-b9a2-7d11be431877",
        "X-Runtime": "0.053501",
        "Vary": "Origin",
        "X-Rack-CORS": "preflight-hit; no-origin",
        "Content-Length": "822"
      },
      "response_content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "curl": "curl \"http://localhost:3000/scores\" -X GET \\\n\t-H \"Accept: application/json\" \\\n\t-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \\\n\t-H \"Host: example.org\" \\\n\t-H \"Cookie: \""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How is this json file generated in the first place? Seems strange to have all those headers in it. It's as if another request is being made and not parsing response out

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` to parse `response_body` into json:

```
$.getJSON(link_name,
    function(data){
        var body= JSON.parse(data["requests"][0]["response_body"]);
        var id = body["scores"][0]["id"];
    }
);
```

example: https://jsbin.com/bewopenoqo/edit?js,console